# html, stop loading js scripts until one with async/await finishes executing

Tags: javascript, html, asynchronous

I have typical html:

```
...
//head
<script type="module" scr="script_1.js"></script>

//some libraries scripts, some html, body etc...
//footer
<script type="module" scr="script_2.js"></script>
...
```

script_1 contains downloading translations with axios and saving them in window.globalThis. script_2 requires these translations. Unfortunately, because of the asynchrony, script_2 will start executing before script_1 finishes. Of course I can import script_1 directly into script_2 checking if the needed data is ready and downloading if not. But because I have to watch out for performance, I'd rather prepare the translations at the start of the application, and only then load the next files. Maybe someone has an idea how to do it from the html level, or how to build the download of translations in script_1 so that it ends first, and then the next files are loaded?

Simply: can I delay the loading of html files until the first containing async/await finishes executing? Is it possible at all?

Comment: you have to add script dynamically in dom.

Comment: `can I delay the loading of html files until the first containing async/await finishes executing?` this contrasts with `I have to watch out for performance`. It basically is the same as importing script1 into script2

Answer (score -1):

Directly delaying the loading of scripts based on asynchronous actions is not possible. To do this, dispatch a custom event in the first script when your async operation is finished, and then dynamically load the second script in response to that event.

Try this;

```
<!-- In the <head> section -->
<script type="module" src="script_1.js"></script>

<!-- In the <footer> section -->
<script>
  document.addEventListener('translationsReady', function() {
    const script2 = document.createElement('script');
    script2.type = 'module';
    script2.src = 'script_2.js';
    document.body.appendChild(script2);
  });
</script>
```

hope it works :)

Comment: This seems good, but unfortunately even after re-reading about addEventListener I don't know where it comes from and what exactly 'translationsReady' is. Could I ask for an explanation?